# Implementing a string-find method

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a function, that searches for the first occurrence of a passed string in a global variable. When found, I want it to return the matching char as a pointer.

This however, doesn't work:

> warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by
>   default]

```
char *find(const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    const char *ptr = s;

    while(ptr[i])
    {
        //wordList is a global struct with a string
        if(ptr[i] == wordList->search[0])
        {
            return ptr[i];
        }
        else i+=1;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You are not verifying that both strings are equal by doing this `ptr[i] == wordList->search[0]`, but only the first character of each string

Comment: In there is a need to pass an array of pointers you mean it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptr[i]` is of type `char`. You need to return a `char` pointer from your function as its return type is `char *`. Use

```
return &ptr[i];
```

As  [Bit Fiddling Code Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2993960/bit-fiddling-code-monkey) pointed in his comment, better to change the return type of your function

```
const char *find(const char *s) { ... }
```

Comment: `return (char *)&ptr[i];` should remove the warning that @IMX is getting.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey; Yes. But it has some pits and falls also.

Comment: Changing the function header to `const char *find(const char *s)'  would be better, I reckon.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey; Yes. That would be better.

Answer (score 3):

You want to return `&ptr[i]` - your code is returning the value of the character found cast to a pointer.

Also, you are taking in a `const char*` and returning a `char *` - you should probably fix that - either change the return type or `s` and `ptr`. Also, you don't need `ptr` - you can do the whole thing dereferencing `s` directly.

oh, and if you stick with the consts and we are being picky, then it should probably be `const char* const s`

Comment: `warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]`

Comment: @IMX Try: `return (char *)ptr`

Comment: casting away const is nasty, and usually means you have got your signatures wrong (as is this case).

Comment: @OliverMatthews Good point.  Maybe change the function header to `const char *find(const char *s)`